# How to use DirectX 11 with Visual Studio 2015 toolset v140 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directx-11, visual-studio-2015

I'm making the project based on DirectX 11. Previously, I've been developing it with Visual Studio 2012 with v110 toolset. Then I got a need in using C++ 11 standard, so I decided to move it to the Visual Studio 2015. Also I'm using Windows 7, and want my project to be compatible with this platform (so I use standard Win project, not for universal platform).

And here I've got a problem with the new VS toolset v140. Due to using DirectX 11 2010 June SDK I faced the next compilation errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1275): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'DXGI_RGBA'
```

I'm also using effects11 and D3DX. So I had to recompile effects11 with the new toolset. What about D3DX library - I know that it is not recomended to use. It seems to me that exactly this library causes compilation errors.

Also I've checked the usage of DirectX 11 directly from Windows Kits in a new clear project (in my case it is using 8.1 kit). It works fine without D3DX library.

Is there any way to use D3DX library and Win Kits at the same time, so that it won't create compatibility problems? Or should I use some library instead of D3DX (like DXTK)?

**UPD**

I've tried to exclude D3DX from my project and D3DX11Tex and fully adapt it for Windows Kits\8.1\ + DirectXMath + DirectXTex (library from Microsoft's Git). The next error has occured 6 times:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtree(2047): error C3848: expression having type 'const `anonymous-namespace'::StringCompare' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool `anonymous-namespace'::StringCompare::operator ()(PCHAR,PCHAR)'
```

The directory where xtree.h contained is automaticaly included in the project pathes. And as I understand it is ok.

The code whick causes this error is next:

```
bool _Compare(const key_type& _Left, const key_type& _Right) const
{   // compare key_type to key_type, with debug checks
    return (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(), _Left, _Right));
}
```

And all 6 errors point on that code in *xtree.h*. By the way, I include *d3d11.h*  in many headers, which are linked to each other many times (so like the *d3d11.h* is not on the top of hierarchy as single include but every file in hierarchy has include of *this* header).

**Qestions:** Where is this file used (I don't include it directly)? Could it be some king of a link problem? Or is it again some kind of conflict between some versions (I don't know how, just because I don't use Dx11 June 2010 SDK, and don't try to link some not existing headers like *D3DX11Tex*)?

**SOLUTION:**
The problem with *xtree.h* was in self-defined functor for *std::map* with NON-constant operator(). So changing it to a constant one solved all 6 errors.

What about DirectX question... Unfortunately it is realy no way to use old version with a new VS. So as it was mentioned in answers and comments, don't use D3DX at all. Thanks to all!

Comment: Be sure to see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).

Comment: Why is this flagged close?  It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: It is like realy no way to use old DirectX 11 SDK (June 2010) with the new sdk from Win Kits. All what you need is changing all "old code" to a new one from libraries, mentioned in answers. The last thing what you will need to do is to force **correct** _WIN32_WINNT version, because new libraries use it to decide what functions should be used (for example CreateFile2 (Win8 and newer) or CreateFile (Win7 compatible). I'm not sure that I have to put this into the solution and should I remove my own problem with xtree, which I thought was connected somehow with DirectX sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The June 2010 SDK is very old, and conflicts with the most recent Windows kits, as you have seen. Direct3DX has also been deprecated, and there is no real work being done on it any more.

Part of it has been rewritten by Microsoft on a public GitHub account, named [dxtk](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). You may consider using that. However, you will not be able to get the original D3DX to work with a modern version of the Windows SDK.

The solution to your problem is to remove the dependency on the June 2010 DirectX SDK, and replace the part of your project that uses the deprecated features. As a replacement, use either dxtk or your own rewrite of the feature.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried, but have got new errors with xtree.h. Do you have any ideas of what can cause these errors?

Comment: Are you using the Effects 11 from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/fx11) as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly this [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11). I've checked all dependencies - all includes of directx are from Win Kits\8.1.